# TableViewer : limit the height of Table in section

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, miglayout

i have many section in FormPage on EclipseRPC.
in a Section, i have a TableViewer with Add and others buttons.

My problem is simple. the items are added correctly to the table and the table keep his same height and vertical scrollbar appears (Perfect). But when I reopen the page, the table expands (height) to display all of the items while the table has a vertical scrollbar.

I want the table height to remain fixed.

Her my code

```
private void createSectionStructureSimple(FormToolkit toolkit, ScrolledForm form) {
        
        Section section = toolkit.createSection(form.getBody(), Section.DESCRIPTION|Section.TITLE_BAR|Section.EXPANDED|Section.TWISTIE);
        
        section.setText("Structure simple");
        section.setDescription("Indiquez ci-dessous les donn\u00e9es brutes de structures simples et les donn\u00e9es communes qui seront export\u00e9es :");
        section.setLayoutData("grow");
    
        MigLayout lm = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[grow] []","[] [] [] [grow]");
        Composite comp = toolkit.createComposite(section);
        comp.setLayout(lm);
        
        Label label = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Nom du fichier CSV : ");
        FontDescriptor boldDescriptor = FontDescriptor.createFrom(label.getFont()).setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
        Font boldFont = boldDescriptor.createFont(label.getDisplay());
        label.setFont( boldFont );
        toolkit.createLabel(comp, "");
        

        filenameSimpleField = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        filenameSimpleField.setLayoutData("grow");
        filenameSimpleField.setText(metaInfo.getNomFichierExportStructureSimple());
        filenameSimpleField.addModifyListener(new StructureSimpleNameModifyListener(metaInfo));
        toolkit.createLabel(comp, "");
    
        Table managerTable = toolkit.createTable(comp, SWT.MULTI);
        TableViewer viewerStructSimple = new TableViewer(managerTable);
        managerTable.setLayoutData("span 1 4, grow");
        
        addDonneesimple = toolkit.createButton(comp, "Ajouter donnée brute", SWT.PUSH); 
        addDonneesimple.addSelectionListener(new StructureSimpleAddingListener((PollEditor)getEditor(), getSite(), viewerStructSimple, toolkit));
        addDonneesimple.setLayoutData("growx");
        
        suppDonneesimple = toolkit.createButton(comp, "Supprimer donnée brute", SWT.PUSH); 
        suppDonneesimple.setLayoutData("growx");
        suppDonneesimple.setEnabled(false);
        suppDonneesimple.addSelectionListener(new StructureSimpleDeletionListener(getSite(), viewerStructSimple));
        viewerStructSimple.addSelectionChangedListener(new StructureSimpleTableSelectionListener(suppDonneesimple));
        viewerStructSimple.setContentProvider(new StructureSimpleContentProvider(this));
        viewerStructSimple.setLabelProvider(new StructureSimpleLabelProvider());
        viewerStructSimple.setInput(((PollEditor) getEditor()).getMetaInfo());
        CapibaraUIActivator.getDefault().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(comp);
        section.setClient(comp);

    }
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem but you are leaking the `boldFont` resource in this code - you need to dispose of the font when the form is disposed. Or use a `FontRegistry` to manage it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even it doesn't concerned my problem. I will fix it.

Comment: Instead of explaining the layout with words you could just add a screenshot where you mark the "faulty" section with paint. That would help me a lot to understand the problem.